# Chiral tunneling in Weyl Equation

Tags: symmetry, dirac-equation, quantum-tunneling, chirality

I am trying to understand perfect tunneling of particles obeying Weyl equation through a potential barrier at normal incidence. I know that this has something to do with chirality, but I am not exactly sure what. Can someone explain how chirality and tunneling related?

Comment: Do you know about the interaction Hamiltonian of the system you are considering?

Comment: The Hamiltonian is the usual Weyl equation with a square potential barrier added to it.